# Viber does not launch

Tags: software-installation, viber

I have installed Viber 64 bit version and it worked just after the installation. However once I closed it, there is no way to launch it again.

I even tried going to install directory and launching still nothing happens.
Please help..

Comment: Try starting it up via terminal, and then see what kinda error it throws at you

Comment: Hi, I did, it doesn't give any error or feed back, it just go to the next line like nothing happened. But still it doesn't launch.

Comment: Purge and reinstall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just released a new version of Viber for Linux. Please update your Viber version at http://www.viber.com/en/products/linux and this should resolve your launch issue.

Comment: It still doesn't work sometimes

Comment: for me it never worked, i tried both deb and rpm... any solution?

Comment: In some cases, there could be a Viber process already running which prevents you to launch viber. Try: ps aux | grep Viber in terminal. If it shows a viber process already running, kill it by: sudo kill -9 <viber_process_id_from_previous_command>. Try launching viber again.

Comment: 22.04 segaults, now does not start event after clean installation